# SQLAlchemy raises exception on query when with_polymorphic used for model with order_by mapper arg presented with string

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I've stuck with one issue when using SQLA inheritance (I have mixin with `__mapper_args__` set there).

To reproduce it:

- Model should have `__mapper_arg__` attribute with `order_by` param set to any string.
- add `with_polymorphic('*')` call to query with this Model.

```python
class User(Base):
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)

    __mapper_args__ = {'order_by': 'User.name'}
```

With this constructions everything works just fine except when we add `with_polymorphic('*')` to query.

```python
db.query(User).with_polymorphic('*')
```

This fails with exception

```
File "/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/visitors.py", line 267, in clone
    'no_replacement_traverse' in elem._annotations:
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute '_annotations'
```

I suppose this is kind of a bug. But since It reproduces on SQLA 0.7-0.9 I have doubts about my way I've run into this issue. Maybe I do something wrong?

This issue was reproduced on [small testcase](http://pastebin.com/du7hjyAQ).

---

P.S.

Originally I needed this mixin in my project:

```python
class DocMixin(object):

    id = Column(Integer)
    title = Column(String(255))

    @declared_attr
    def __mapper_args__(cls):
        return {'order_by': 'title'}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use strings in `order_by` mapper parameter, use column directly. Changing `'User.name'` to `name` makes your example to pass tests.

Comment: Unfortunately it does not work for y case, when I have field in MixIn.
When i use

Comment: @Lehych What is the problem with using `cls.title` instead of `'title'` here?

Comment: Then I got an exception: `CompileError: Cannot compile Column object until it's 'name' is assigned`.
I think I finaly found related question https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sqlalchemy/Y5Tc-e3vZGI where Michael Bayer says about solution only for SQLA>0.8.

Comment: @Lehych If you need a solution for some specific version of SQLAlchemy you'd better state this in the question.

Comment: Now I see that that the question is a bit messy as the most of there are complaining about the bug, not about my quetsion. All the question about Using model mixin with declared field that should be used in order clause of descendant model (I wrote it in p.s. section). This all in python2.7 with sqlalchemy 0.7.